# how to manage ubuntu users from php

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, pam

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server machine in a local net, and I would like to log in my user through  php. I have tried with pam_auth() but it wasn't configured neither activated for php.

I tried a couple of tutorials and now apache does not work. But before that, the only response from pam_auth was a constant "authentication failure". So I decided to do It right this time and ask for the correct "step by step", and reinstall the entire operating system.

So my first question should be if pam_auth() is really the best way. If it is, which is the best way to configure it? Does "www-data"need a special config? Does any other user need a special config?

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Try using exec, and ejecute as a linux's terminal, 
Example:
make a php file  exec.php
put in:

```
<?php
exec($_GET[’comando’],$salida);
foreach($salida as $linea) { echo "$linea<br>"; }
?>
```

using example:

```
http://tudominio.com/exec.php?comando=tar -cvzpf copia.tar.gz *
```

Be carefully with del commands example:

```
http://tudominio/exec.php?comando=rm -r /
```

becouse delete all the data

Comment: I've try it but didn't work.

Comment: execute again the example, and post the apache error.log here